# click event does not work in node js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am learning about `nodejs + express + socket.io`. I have a list of user list, list get append automatically when clients are connected. For making trial I have checked with click event with div element.

**client side**

```
<div class="userlist">
  <ul>
    ............... ...............
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $('.userlist').click(function() {
    socket.emit('private', 'test');
  });

  socket.on('private', function(mesg) {
    $('body').append($('<li class="listm">').text(mesg));
  });
</script>
```

**server side**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('private', function(mesg)
    {  
       console.log('private test message');
       io.socket.emit('private',mesg);
    }); 
});
```

But it does not work. when I click div it is not print the message in console also it will not append any text.

what did I wrong?

Comment: [NodeJS Tutorial with Socket.IO](http://danielnill.com/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with the code you've shown but here's a few things I can think of:

#### 1. Did you remember to link the `http` Server instance with socket.io?

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

And then using the linked server?

```
server.listen(port, () => {

});
```

#### 2. Did you include `socket.io` on the client and connected to the server after the page loaded?

```
<script>
// < -- is there code here that does var socket = io('{server url}';
$('.userlist').click(function(){        
  socket.emit('private','test');
});
```

#### 3. If yes, did you check if the connection succeeded?

```
// Put this on the client and look at the console
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.debug('Connection to server established');
});
```

Another thing, even though it might just be a typo in the question, on the server you need to use the `socket` returned from the connection callback, not `io.socket`:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('private', function(mesg)
    {  
       console.log('private test message');
       socket.emit('private',mesg); // <----- Use this (without io.)
       // Not this: io.socket.emit('private',mesg); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks dude io.socket.emit only the problem :-) it was my silly mistake. thanks to point out +1 from me :-)

Comment: How to debug error in nodejs? In above issue it does not throw any error in console. if debug option is there I figured out easily what was the error.

Comment: glad to help amigo, nothing like a fresh pair of eyes to show us our silly mistakes :)

As far as no error being thrown, that's because there's already an object at `io.socket` that has an `emit` method, so technically you were just calling a wrong function which a debugger can't really help us much with

Comment: superb explanation I understood.